# Multiple pointers to an object defined in the heap

Tags: c++, pointers

Let's say I have a temp pointer to a Student object (doesn't matter what the definition of Student is - let's say it contains no pointer data members), which I'm using as follows :

```
int main(){
Student *temp;
Student *s1 = new s1("John", 21);
Student *s2 = new s2("Jane", 23);
//do whatever;
temp = s1;
s1 = s2;
s2 = temp;

delete s1;
delete s2;

return 0;
}
```

Since I used `new` for `s1` and `s2`, I know the objects are created in the heap, and I need to use the `delete` operator to get rid of them. My question is - do I need to "delete temp"? If not, why? How is "temp's" memory managed? Could someone explain how the memory manager handles this pointer, and what happens to it when it goes out of scope?

Comment: Unrelated: What is `delete s1, s2`?

Comment: 1. What object does `temp` point to? 2. Did you already delete that object through a different pointer? Answer both of those and you should know the answer to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can't delete 2 objects with the same `delete`, so this doesn't work:

```
delete s1, s2;
```

That just deletes the object pointed to by s1, and does nothing to `s2` (see: the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)). Change it to 2 separate statements.

With that out of the way, no you do not have to call `delete` on `temp`, because the object it pointed to (the same one `s2` pointed to) is already destroyed and deallocated with the call:

```
delete s2;
```

You can, however, call `delete temp;` *instead* of `delete s2;`, since they both point to the same object.  You could even do this:

```
delete temp;
temp = s1;
delete temp;
```

`delete` works on objects allocated with `new`, via the pointers that point to them.  It doesn't matter which pointer you call delete on.  It only matters which address is stored in the pointer when you call it.  And that address must be one which was previously returned by `new`, but which hasn't already been deleted.

As for this:

> Could someone explain how the memory manager handles this pointer, and
>   what happens to it when it goes out of scope?

Nothing happens when a pointer goes out of scope.  At least, nothing that doesn't happen to a regular variable like an `int` or a `char`, perhaps a stack pointer gets moved, but that's an implementation detail.

Comment: @srihari pay special attention to the words **"instead of"** in that closing sentence. It is fundamental to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to delete `temp` as this was just a copy of the pointer, since you are deleting the actual allocated buffers. It is an `auto` variable which will be deleted once it goes out of scope.

If your class `Student` overrides the `assignment` operator to make a `copy`, then either you could `delete` the variable explicitly or shall be deleted once the function returns.

Comment: I don't quite understand the second part - do you mean doing a deep copy? If so, wouldn't temp point to a copy of the object pointed to by `s1` in the heap? In that case, wouldn't I have to call `delete temp` explicitly? How will it get deleted when the function returns?

Comment: @Srihari.. Please refer to this link which I feel is a very informative on the subject of calling `delete` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081429/when-is-a-c-destructor-called . Of course, it is definitely a good practice to explicitly call a `delete`, but this is more attributed to `C` programmers than `C++` ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got it - temp is just an integer on the stack, and will be handled by the memory manager once it goes out of scope, like any stack variable.

`temp` and `s1` now point to the same memory location : hence, deleting `s1` takes care of the object `temp` is pointing to. There will be no memory leaks because of `temp`, at this stage. However, if I try to access `temp`, after the `delete s1;` statement, my program will probably crash.

Comment: Note: `temp` is not "an integer on the stack". It is a pointer, the representation of which is implementation-dependant and you don't necessarily know. The rest of your answer is entirely accurate, and it sounds like you understand. +1 (and consider up-voting other helpful answers).

Comment: @WhozCraig : My understanding was that pointers are simply intended to store memory addresses, which in turn are just integers in hexadecimal representation...how _else_ could a pointer be stored? If it is not always stored as an integer, do we need to know how a pointer is implemented before doing pointer arithmetic (for ex., ptr++)? 
(+1 for bringing this up, I didn't know pointers weren't always implemented as integers. :)

Comment: The very term "address" is implementation dependent. And the point is *you don't have to know what "it" actually is* so long as you follow the rules of the standard. There are some *amazing* platforms that do things with their implementation of pointers and addresses that would boggle most minds (AS/400 is one of them).

Comment: It should also be noted that the hexadecimal representation you are used to seeing is just how your `ostream` or `printf` implementers chose to display them.  It has nothing to do with their actual storage, which is in binary just like everything else.