# When is a variable that is "replaced" no longer addressable

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

If I assign a new variable to an old variable, the old variable is no longer addressable, however I'm not sure when it goes out of scope:

for example:

```
std::vector<int> foo() {
    return std::vector<int>{3,4,5};
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};

    v = foo();  //when is the first vectors destructor called? 
                //before or after "foo()" has been called?
                //is it called?

}
```

And, if it isn't called till after foo has been called, how do I destroy v before I call foo()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is a C++ destructor called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081429/when-is-a-c-destructor-called)

Comment: You mean `std::vector<int> v{ 3, 4, 5 }; return v;`, right?

Comment: A destructor for `v` or for the vector returned from `foo()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v = foo();
```

The above statement is a move assignment (copy assignment for pre-C++11 compilers). In either case, the result of the call to `foo()` is required for the assignment, since it is the input argument to the respective assignment operator, so the freeing of resources managed by `v` is done *after* the call to `foo()`, and the memory management is performed within the copy/move assignment operator.

Notice I didn't mention any calls to the *destructor* of `v`, because the destructor will not be called at that point. The memory that is being managed by `v` will be deallocated, with the destructors for the individual elements being invoked. In case of a `vector<int>`, the destructor of each `int` is a NOP, so they're only conceptually invoked.

The `vector` will then allocate enough memory to be able to hold the contents of the `vector` returned by `foo` (copy assignment), or take control of the memory being managed by the `vector` returned by `foo` (move assignment). Of course, the `vector` implementation is free to skip the deallocation followed by allocation if the existing memory is large enough to hold the new contents.

The destructor for `v` will run when `v` goes out of scope. In the example you've provided, this happens at the end of `main()`.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that the statement about memory allocation is wrong. On copy assignment, the capacity is conserved, and a deallocation/new allocation would break this.

Comment: @MSalters Capacity can only be conserved if the source size is `<=` destination capacity. You may be right about that case, but a quick look through the standard didn't show any such requirements. But, as I mentioned in the answer, implementations will take advantage of that fact and avoid deallocation + allocation. Anyway, there are other nuances to assignment also, introduced by `allocator_traits<T>::propagate_on_container_*()` traits, that I've avoided mentioning in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `foo()` is created prior to assigning it to `v` in `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

The destructor is called when it goes out of scope, that is at the end of main.

The sequence is that you call foo(),  which returns a vector. Then a copy assignment operator is called, which copies the returned vector to the original one. Afterwards the returned vector is destroyed, as it is a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

`v` will only be destructed when it goes out of scope.

However, `foo()` creates a temporary object, which is then returned, which is then assigned to `v`. The temporary is then destroyed (after it has been assigned to `v`). `v` is then destroyed at the end of `main()`.

Note that in practice, the compiler optimizes a lot of this -- it does *return value optimization*, so that instead of returning a temporary which is then assigned to `v`, it works directly on `v`. Also, there's a move assignment operator which swaps the ownership of the memory from the temporary into `v` without doing a copy of it first.