# Public member function not returning values ... am I missing something?

Tags: c++, class

I'm new to C++ (and OOP in general).  I'm writing a class that performs some mathematical operations on 2 polynomials.  Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Poly
{

private:

    int order;                                  // the order of the polynomial
    int *coeff;                                 // pointer to an array of coefficients
                                                // size of the coefficient array is predicated on [order + 1]

public:

//  Poly();                                     // the default constructor
    int setOrderAndCoeff();                     // sets the order and coefficients
    int display();                              // displays the resutling polynomial
    void addition(Poly P1, Poly P2);            // adds 2 polynomials
    void subtraction (Poly P1, Poly P2);        // subtracts 2 polynomials
    void multiplication (Poly P1, Poly P2);     // multiplies 2 polynomials

//  ~Poly();                                    // the destructor
};

//Poly::Poly()
//{
//  order = 0;
//  *coeff = 0;
//}

int Poly::display()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = order; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << coeff[i] << "x^" << i;
        if ((i - 1) != -1)
        {
            cout << "+";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}

int Poly::setOrderAndCoeff()
{
    int i;
    cout << "Please enter the order of the polynomial: ";
    cin >> order;
    coeff = new int[order + 1];
    for (i = order; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the coefficient of x^" << i << " :";
        cin >> coeff[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

void Poly::addition(Poly P1, Poly P2)
{
    int max;
    int i;
    max = (P1.order > P2.order) ? P1.order : P2.order;
    int *add = new int[max + 1];

    if (P1.order == P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P1.coeff[i] + P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }

    if (P1.order > P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P1.order; i > P2.order; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P1.coeff[i];
        }
        for (i = P2.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P1.coeff[i] + P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }

    if (P1.order < P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P2.order; i > P1.order; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P2.coeff[i];
        }
        for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P1.coeff[i] + P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "\nAddition:";
    display();
    cout << "\n";
}

void Poly::subtraction(Poly P1, Poly P2)
{
    int max;
    int i;
    max = (P1.order > P2.order) ? P1.order : P2.order;
    int *sub = new int[max + 1];

    if (P1.order == P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = P1.coeff[i] - P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }

    if (P1.order > P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P1.order; i > P2.order; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = P1.coeff[i];
        }
        for (i = P2.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = P1.coeff[i] - P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }

    if (P1.order < P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P2.order; i > P1.order; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = -P2.coeff[i];
        }
        for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = P1.coeff[i] - P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "\nSubtraction:";
    display();
    cout << "\n";
}

void Poly::multiplication(Poly P1, Poly P2)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int max;

    max = P1.order + P2.order;
    int *mult = new int[max + 1];

    for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
    for (j = P2.order; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        mult[i + j] += P1.coeff[i] * P2.coeff[i];
    }
        cout << "\nMultiplication:";
        display();
}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    Poly P1, P2, P3;
    cout << "-------- Instructions --------" << endl;

    cout << "For polynomial 1... " << endl;
    P1.setOrderAndCoeff();

    cout << endl;

    cout << "For polynomial 2... " << endl;
    P2.setOrderAndCoeff();

    while (1)
    {
        cout << "\n******** Menu Selection ********" << endl;
        cout << "1: Addition\n2: Subtraction\n3: Mutiplication\n0: Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter your choice (1, 2, 3 or 0):";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "\n-------- Addition --------\n";
            cout << "Polynomial 1: ";
            P1.display();
            cout << "Polynomial 2: ";
            P2.display();
            P3.addition(P1, P2);
            cout << "--------------------------\n";
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "\n-------- Subtraction --------\n";
            cout << "Polynomial 1: ";
            P1.display();
            cout << "Polynomial 2: ";
            P2.display();
            P3.subtraction(P1, P2);
            cout << "--------------------------\n";
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "\n-------- Multiplication --------\n";
            cout << "Polynomial 1: ";
            P1.display();
            cout << "Polynomial 2: ";
            P2.display();
            P3.multiplication(P1, P2);
            cout << "--------------------------\n";
            break;

        case 0:
            cout << "The program will now terminate.  Thank you." << endl;
            exit(0);

        default:
            cout << endl;
            cout << "You have entered an invalid selection." << endl;
            cout << "Please enter a positive integer between 0 and 3.";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Everything compiles, and the user is prompted to enter an order and some coefficients.  Unfortunately, the addition(), subtraction() and multiplication() functions aren't returning the resulting polynomial.

I know I'm missing something very elementary, but I can't figure out what it is!

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can give!

PS:  do I even need a default constructor?

---

**EDIT (updated code based on suggested revisions)**

The following is the revised code based on the suggestions:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Poly
{

private:

    int order;                                  // the order of the polynomial
    int *coeff;                                 // pointer to an array of coefficients
                                                // size of the coefficient array is predicated on [order + 1]
    int *add;
    int *sub;
    int *mult;

public:

//  Poly();                                     // the default constructor
    int setOrderAndCoeff();                     // sets the order and coefficients
    int display(int *data, int count);          // displays the resutling polynomial
    void addition(Poly P1, Poly P2);            // adds 2 polynomials
    void subtraction (Poly P1, Poly P2);        // subtracts 2 polynomials
    void multiplication (Poly P1, Poly P2);     // multiplies 2 polynomials

//  ~Poly();                                    // the destructor
};


int Poly::display(int *data, int count)
{
    for (i = cout; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << data[i] << "x^" << i;
        if ((i - 1) != -1)
        {
            cout << "+";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}

int Poly::setOrderAndCoeff()
{
    int i;
    cout << "Please enter the order of the polynomial: ";
    cin >> order;
    coeff = new int[order + 1];
    for (i = order; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the coefficient of x^" << i << " :";
        cin >> coeff[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

void Poly::addition(Poly P1, Poly P2)
{
    int max;
    int i;
    max = (P1.order > P2.order) ? P1.order : P2.order;
    add = new int [max + 1];

    if (P1.order == P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P1.coeff[i] + P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }

    if (P1.order > P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P1.order; i > P2.order; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P1.coeff[i];
        }
        for (i = P2.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P1.coeff[i] + P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }

    if (P1.order < P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P2.order; i > P1.order; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P2.coeff[i];
        }
        for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            add[i] = P1.coeff[i] + P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "\nAddition:";
    display(add, count);
    cout << "\n";
}

void Poly::subtraction(Poly P1, Poly P2)
{
    int max;
    int i;
    max = (P1.order > P2.order) ? P1.order : P2.order;
    int *sub = new int[max + 1];

    if (P1.order == P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = P1.coeff[i] - P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }

    if (P1.order > P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P1.order; i > P2.order; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = P1.coeff[i];
        }
        for (i = P2.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = P1.coeff[i] - P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }

    if (P1.order < P2.order)
    {
        for (i = P2.order; i > P1.order; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = -P2.coeff[i];
        }
        for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sub[i] = P1.coeff[i] - P2.coeff[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "\nSubtraction:";
    display(sub, count);
    cout << "\n";
}

void Poly::multiplication(Poly P1, Poly P2)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int max;

    max = P1.order + P2.order;
    int *mult = new int[max + 1];

    for (i = P1.order; i >= 0; i--)
    for (j = P2.order; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        mult[i + j] += P1.coeff[i] * P2.coeff[i];
    }
        cout << "\nMultiplication:";
        display(mult, count);
}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    Poly P1, P2, P3;
    cout << "-------- Instructions --------" << endl;

    cout << "For polynomial 1... " << endl;
    P1.setOrderAndCoeff();

    cout << endl;

    cout << "For polynomial 2... " << endl;
    P2.setOrderAndCoeff();

    while (1)
    {
        cout << "\n******** Menu Selection ********" << endl;
        cout << "1: Addition\n2: Subtraction\n3: Mutiplication\n0: Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter your choice (1, 2, 3 or 0):";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "\n-------- Addition --------\n";
            cout << "Polynomial 1: ";
            P1.display(add, count);
            cout << "Polynomial 2: ";
            P2.display(add, count);
            P3.addition(P1, P2);
            cout << "--------------------------\n";
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "\n-------- Subtraction --------\n";
            cout << "Polynomial 1: ";
            P1.display(sub, count);
            cout << "Polynomial 2: ";
            P2.display(sub, count);
            P3.subtraction(P1, P2);
            cout << "--------------------------\n";
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "\n-------- Multiplication --------\n";
            cout << "Polynomial 1: ";
            P1.display(mult, count);
            cout << "Polynomial 2: ";
            P2.display(sub, count);
            P3.multiplication(P1, P2);
            cout << "--------------------------\n";
            break;

        case 0:
            cout << "The program will now terminate.  Thank you." << endl;
            exit(0);

        default:
            cout << endl;
            cout << "You have entered an invalid selection." << endl;
            cout << "Please enter a positive integer between 0 and 3.";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm still getting some build errors, namely:

1) i is not defined in

```
int Poly::display(int *data, int count)
```

2) add is an undeclared identifier in case 1 of the switch (as is the case with sub and mult, but it's the same error)

3) in

```
void Poly::addition(Poly P1, Poly P2`)
```

can't convert argument 2 to int

Thanks in advance to everyone for taking a look.

-Ryan

Comment: Yes. You are missing a non-void return type and a return statement in each of those functions.

Comment: @OP, Use Vectors! If you go down this road, you're going to need a [***destructor***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081429/when-is-a-c-destructor-called)

Comment: @user3407254 - Next time, please use the incremental approach of developing a program.  You wrote all of these functions (addition, subtraction, multiplication) without testing each one as it was built.  So now you don't know where the error may be, since you wrote the entire code in one shot.

Comment: @user3407254 - In addition, your code leaks memory all over the place. You have memory leaks every time an options is selected more than once, let alone you've commented out the destructor, causing more issues. Use std::vector, as the goal should be to create a polynomial solver, not a dynamic array class.

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect a function not returning a value to return a value? When you have

```
void addition(Poly P1, Poly P2);
```

there is no way this function to return a value. As a first step you should change it to

```
Poly addition(Poly P1, Poly P2);
```

and add appropriate `return` statement in the function. But it is still not the way it is normally done in C++. You do not want to pass your `Poly` objects by value because it is costly, and with your current definition it leaks memory. You should use

```
Poly addition(const Poly& P1, const Poly& P2);
```

and as the last - but most important - remark. Do not use pointers. Replace your

```
int *coeff;
```

with

```
std::vector<int> coeff;
```

Manual memory allocation should be used only if you know what you are doing and in low-level implementations. For your purpose `std::vector` is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by `returning` you meant `displaying`. The thing is that `sub`,  `add` and `mult` are not visible from `Poly::display` function. Simple, try adding this variables as members of the `Poly` class.

```
class Poly
{

private:

    int order;                                  // the order of the polynomial
    int *coeff;                                 // pointer to an array of coefficients
    int *add, *sub, *mult;                       

// ...
};
```

then you don't have to declare them in each function for instance in `Poly::addition(Poly P1, Poly P2)` you can change:

```
int *add = new int[max + 1];
```

by

```
add = new int[max + 1]; // Or 
                        // this->add = new int[max + 1];
                        // if you prefer.
```

**EDIT:** You are displaying `coeff` content in function `display` and `coeff` don't change when you call any of the operations.

You have to make some modifications to function `display`, the easiest whay is to redefine display to accept 2 parameters:

```
class Poly
{

puplic:
    // ...
    void display(int *data, int count);
    // ...
};

int Poly::display(int *data, int count)
{
    for (int i = count; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << data[i] << "x^" << i;
        if ((i - 1) != -1)
        {
            cout << "+";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and then in (for instance) `Poly::addition`:

```
void Poly::addition(Poly P1, Poly P2)
{
    //...
    display(add, count)  // Here count is the ammount if elements in data.
}
```

Comment: yes, I meant "displaying".  Sorry about that.  When I add "*add", "*sub" and "*mult" as private member variables, and also replace "int *add = new int[max + 1];" with "add = new int[max + 1];", I see the same behavior (the resulting polynomial isn't displayed when I select "1" to invoke addition.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you.  I've updated the code based on your suggestions.  In "int Poly::display(int *data, int count)", I'm seeing i as being undefined.  How would we define that?  I've edited the post to include the updated code.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3407254 Sorry my bad, in the display function in the foor loop must read `for (int i = count ...)`. Note the `int` keyword. On the other hand int the for loop again is **count** no **cout**

Comment: OK, I've updated the for loop (int i and count instead of cout).  When I try to build, I see that "display(add, count)" is giving an error that reads "error C2664: 'int Poly::display(int *,int)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type (__cdecl *)(_InIt,_InIt,const _Ty &)' to 'int'".  Any idea what's causing this?    I've posted the revised code above.  Thanks again (and I will upvote).

Comment: @user3407254 - You did not post what `count` in the call to display really is.  All you did was describe what it is.  It certainly isn't a simple integer -- if it were, then the error should not have occurred, or that `display` function isn't the one you're showing us.  Second, to repeat, your code may "work", but it is a patchwork that is full of mistakes, as outlined by the other comments and answers.