# Destructor never call

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't understand why the destructor of *ListELement* is never call.
 I use the class *Base* as counter, *ListELement* derive from *Base* to use the counter.

The Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Base{
    protected:
    static int count;
};


template <class T>
class ListElement: public Base{

    public:
    ListElement(const T& value): next(NULL), data(value) { count++;}
    ~ListElement() { cout<<"dead:"<<count<<endl;}

    //Setter
    void SetData(const T& value) { data=value; }
    void SetNext(ListElement* elem) { next = elem; }
    //Getter
    const T& GetData() const { return data; }
    ListElement* GetNext() const { return next; } 

    private:
    T data; 
    ListElement* next;
};

int Base::count = 0;

int main(){
    random_device rd;
    default_random_engine generator(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,100);
    auto dice = bind(distribution, generator);

    int nListSize = 1;
    ListElement<int>* nMyList = new ListElement<int>(999);

    ListElement<int>* temp = nMyList;//nMyList is the first element
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        ListElement<int>* k = new ListElement<int>(dice()); //New element
        temp->SetNext(k);
        temp = temp->GetNext(); 
        nListSize++;    
    }

    temp=nMyList;
    for(int i=0; i<nListSize; ++i){
        cout<<"Value["<<i<<"]: "<<temp->GetData()<<endl;
        temp = temp->GetNext();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my output:

```
Value[0]: 999
Value[1]: 61
Value[2]: 14
Value[3]: 96
Value[4]: 51
Value[5]: 15
Value[6]: 37
Value[7]: 83
Value[8]: 1
Value[9]: 42
Value[10]: 95
```

If I type `echo &?` the console return my `0` so everything should be fine.

Comment: If you create an object with `new`, you have to destroy it manually with `delete`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is a C++ destructor called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081429/when-is-a-c-destructor-called)

Comment: OK! but when the program exit it should destroy everything, right?

Comment: You should also run the compilation with `-Wall` and `-Werror` any time you have issues such as this one.

Comment: When program exists it releases back the memory to the system, it doesn't go around calling random destructors :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `new` a few `ListElement<int>` but never `delete` them.

Destructors are automatically called for variables with automatic-storage duration. They aren't for variables for which you manually allocate memory.

If you add the proper delete statements, you'll have the dtors running.

Note: If you absolutely need a pointer, you should look into `std::shared_ptr`/`std::unique_ptr` as you'll have the semantics of a pointer, with the memory management done for you, i.e. the pointer will be properly deleted once it's not referenced anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For each explicit `new` call, you will need an explicit `delete` call unless your *ListElement* destructor has a loop to *delete* those nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Because an object created with operator new must be explicitly released using operator delete.

This can be achieved by using facilities from  and either changing the type of nMyList to (before C++-11)

```
std::auto_ptr<ListElement<int> > nMyList(new ListElement<int>(999));
```

or (from C++11, which deprecates auto_ptr)

```
std::unique_ptr<ListElement<int> > nMyList(new ListElement<int>(999));
```

If you insist on not changing the type of nMyList,  then

```
delete nMyList;
```

at the end of main() will also work (the advantage of smart pointer types being that they destroy the object they manage).