# When exactly destructor of a class invoked in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to C++. I have written below code for understanding how constructor and destructor works in C++.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Line
{
    private:
        Line();
    public:
        int length;
        static void getInstance(Line* objLine);
        ~Line();
};

void Line::getInstance(Line* objLine)
{
    if(objLine == NULL)
    {
        objLine = new Line();
    }
}

Line::Line()
{
    cout<<"In the Constructor"<<endl;
}

Line::~Line()
{
    cout<<"In the Destructor"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    Line* objLine = NULL;
    Line::getInstance(objLine);
    return 0;
}
```

I have read that destructor of a class is invoked when object goes out of scope. In above code object is handled by objLine which is a local variable. So at the end of the main i have expected destructor to be invoked. But it is never getting invoked. Any one please tell me when destructor is invoked in above case

Comment: `objLine` goes out of scope as `main` ends, but `objLine` is *not* an instance of `Line`, it is simply a pointer. So a pointer goes out of scope at the end of `main`. It has no destructor. If you had written `Line objLine` instead, the destructor would have executed as `objLine` went out of scope.

Comment: For software beyond education I suggest using shared pointers, which invoke the destructor, when variable goes out of scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081429/when-is-a-c-destructor-called

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++, the destructor is called when a variable goes out of scope, or when `delete` is called on an object created with `new`.

You use `new` to create an object, but never use `delete`, hence the destructor is never called.

If your code would be like this:

```
int main() {
   Line objLine;
}
```

the destructor is called.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clean up your own memory in this case

```
int main()
{
    Line* objLine = NULL;
    Line::getInstance(objLine);
    delete objLine;
    return 0;
}
```

This is because you used `new` to allocate the memory, so it won't automatically clean itself up after it falls out of scope. You need to clean up the memory using `delete`

As [@StefanoSanfilippo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30707727/2296458) mentioned, you also need to change your `getInstance` function to

```
void Line::getInstance(Line*& objLine)
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. `objLine` is passed by value to `getInstance` , it isn't modified and therefore `delete objLine` will actually be a call to `delete NULL`, which results in a no op.

Answer (score 2):

The scope rule is valid for automatic allocation (i.e. of local variables). Instead, you are dynamically allocating instances of `Line` using the `new` operator:

```
void Line::getInstance(Line* objLine)
{
    if(objLine == NULL)
    {
        objLine = new Line();
    }
}
```

A dynamically allocated object is not bound to a scope and must be explicitely deleted using `delete` operator. Furthermore, the method above is leaking memory: once you leave the function, you will have lost any reference to the newly created object and therefore you will have no way to access or `delete` it. You'll want to actually modify the pointer you are passed, e.g. by modifying your code as follows:

```
void Line::getInstance(Line** objLine)
{
    if(objLine == NULL)
    {
        *objLine = new Line();
    }
}
```

at this point you can use it like:

```
int main()
{
    Line* objLine = NULL;
    Line::getInstance(&objLine);
    // do something...
    delete objLine;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `The scope rule is valid for static allocation` Actually, statically allocated objects are not destroyed at the end of scope. They're destroyed after `main` returns. You probably meant automatic (stack) allocation.

Comment: @user2079303 I meant _static_ (as in compile-time) as opposed to _dynamic_ (as in runtime), but yes, _automatic_ is more correct and I've edited the post accordingly. I though that _"automatic storage"_  might sound a bit strange to a newcomer.